# recursive adding two list of integer - python

Tags: python, list

I have these two lists of integer:

```
A=[1,5,3]
B=[4,5,9,8]
```

I want to use the recursive method o get the sum of these two , and extra integer just appends to the result.
So I should get:

```
[5,10,12,8]
```

Here are my functions:

```
def sum(A,B):
    a = len(A)
    b = len(B)

    if a == 0 :
        return B
    elif b == 0 :
        return  A
    elif a >= b :

        return A[0] + B[0] + sum(A[1:b],B[1:])+ **list1[(b+1):]**
    else:
        return  A[0] +B[0] + sum(A[1:],B[1:a])+**list2[(a+1):]**
```

For the "****" bold part, i am not sure whether i am correct or not,
and furthermore, when i ran the program, i got 
"return A[0] + B[0] + sum(A[1:b],B[1:])+A[(b+1):]

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive case isn't correct. You should be returning a list sum, meaning your `A[0] + B[0]` must be added as a single element list. Basically, this is what you're doing:

```
In [559]: 1 + [123]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-559-01aa05245fd1> in <module>()
----> 1 1 + [123]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

And this is what you should be doing:

```
In [560]: [1] + [123]
Out[560]: [1, 123]
```

---

Here's a working version of the recursive case, slightly tidied up.

```
In [555]: def sum(A, B):
     ...:     if not len(A):
     ...:         return B
     ...:     elif not len(B):
     ...:         return A
     ...:
     ...:     return [A[0] + B[0]] + sum(A[1:], B[1:])
     ...: 

In [556]: sum(A, B)
Out[556]: [5, 10, 12, 8]
```

---

Fun fact, you can shorten this function to a single line.

```
In [557]: def sum(A, B):
     ...:     return A if not len(B) \
                       else (B if not len(A) \
                       else ([A[0] + B[0]] + sum(A[1:], B[1:])))
     ...: 

In [558]: sum(A, B)
Out[558]: [5, 10, 12, 8]
```

Comment: but still has this problem when I run the program:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'.

Comment: @J.Done I don't think you saved your file.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much !!

Comment: @DamianLattenero Thank you, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum(l1, l2, result = None, id = 0):

    if result is None:
        result = []
    if id < min(len(l1), len(l2)):
        result.append(l1[id] + l2[id])
        return sum(l1, l2, result, id + 1)
    else:
        if len(l1)>len(l2):
          biggest=l1
        else:
          biggest=l2

        return result+biggest[id:]
```

Input

```
r=sum([1,5,3,2],[4,5,9,8,15])
```

Output

```
[5, 10, 12, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-recursive way to do this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,5,3]
>>> b = [4,5,9,8]
>>> [sum(i) for i in itertools.zip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=0)]
[5, 10, 12, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def the_sum(a, b, c):
   if not a[1:] and b[1:]:
       c.append(b[0]+a[0])
       return the_sum(a, b[1:], c)
   if not b[1:]:
       c.append(b[0])
       return c
   if a[1:] and b[1:]:
       c.append(a[0]+b[0])
       return the_sum(a[1:], b[1:], c)

print(the_sum([1,5,3], [4,5,9,8], []))
```

Output:

```
[5, 10, 12, 8]
```